# What is the matter with my javascript?

Tags: javascript

It's not working.

What is the problem?

I am trying put return values, but browser not display anything  :(

Please help me.

I am a newbie so please help me.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function (){
document.write(100+50);
}

function 2(){
document.write(100-50);
}

function 3(){
document.write(100/50);
}

function show(){
1();
2();
2();
}

show();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"In JavaScript, identifiers are used to name variables (and keywords, and functions, and labels). The rules for legal names are much the same in most programming languages. In JavaScript, the first character must be a letter, an underscore (_), or a dollar sign ($)."* (Suggestion by Google for searching "JavaScript identifier rules")

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: The first step of JavaScript debugging is to ALWAYS check the error console.  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can't use numbers as function names

Comment: i Modified   still not wrok                                                               <html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

function one(a,b){
x = a+b;
return x;
}

function two(a,b){
x = a-b;
return x;
}

function three(a,b){
x = a/b;
return x;
}

function show(){
one();
two();
three();
}

show(a,b);

</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: you are not passing a or b to any of the one, two,three functions

Comment: and show does not accept any parameters as written.  you want function show(a,b){one(a,b);two(a,b);three(a,b);}

Answer (score 1):

you gave a number for a name of your functions.You cant do that. Everything in programming languanges has to start with letters pretty much